# How to count total records of SQL before adding pagination and store count value in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, pagination

I've created a `GetData` function as follows:

```
public string GetData(string current, string rowCount, string orderBy, string orderFrom, string searchPhrase)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    var con = new SqlConnection();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    string sSQL = @"SELECT LogID, Severity, Title
                    FROM dbo.Log
                    WHERE UPPER(LogID) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                        OR UPPER(Severity) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                      OR UPPER(Title) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                    ORDER BY " + orderBy + " " + orderFrom + @"
                    OFFSET ((" + (Convert.ToInt32(current) - 1).ToString() + ") * " + rowCount + @") ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT " + rowCount + " ROWS ONLY;";

    try
    {
        using (var connection = THF.Models.SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }

        var total = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        var rows = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        result = "{ \"current\": " + current + ", \"rowCount\": " + rowCount + ", \"rows\": " + rows + ", \"total\": " + total + " }";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see the SQL string will return the number of values based on the `rowCount` which is expected.

Before implementing the pagination functionality I used `var total = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();` to acquire the `total` number of fields in the table. But now that I've implemented pagination this doesn't work because the data table is filled only with the pages number of values.

What is the most efficient implementation to modify my function to get the total number of records in the whole table (not just the page) without affecting the rest of the pagination functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Before you do anything else, read about parameterized queries and Sql injection. Then rewrite all your queries to use parameters. After that, you should add another select statement to return the count of rows based on the where condtion of your paging statement (of course, return only the count and not data, and without the offset...fetch next clause).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'll check it out and edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make another database call like this , Not sure if this the most efficient way

```
public int rowCount(string tableName)
{
    string ssQL = string.Format("SELECT count(*) from {0}", tableName);
    int rowCount;
    using (var connection = THF.Models.SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            rowCount = command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return rowCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply run a

```
select count(*) ...
```

query with the same `from` and `where`, but without the paging part. It is a separate query and reduces performance, but you cannot use the other query, returning a subset of the records you are interested of due to the paging to return the total count as well.

If this is too slow to you, then you will need to optimize it, maybe storing the count in a cache somewhere and refreshing that cache whenever new records are created or removed.

I should mention that the way you are writing the queries is highly unsafe, as it allows [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) with which ill-willing people can wreak havoc on your site.

Comment: My main problem with that is I don't know how to store the vale returned. In my example I use a SQLAdapter to fill a `DataTable`. How do I store the count value?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle you need a data member of the corresponding object's class to be created for this purpose, maybe in the code-behind, if you are working on a WebForms project.